# Installing GitLab on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab

I'm trying to Install GitLab on my Ubuntu 12.04 Server.
First I tried to install the package as mentioned here https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/
But when I start the reconfigure the process stops at this point: "ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run"

So I tried to download and compile the source as mentioned her: http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2014/01/11/setup-your-own-private-github-server-using-gitlab-and-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/

Here everything works fine, till I try to access the site in my webbrowser, where I get a "502
GitLab is not responding." error.

Has someone here an solution for me?

Comment: The link you mention has a fix on `/etc/hosts`, did you check it?

Comment: Yes but nothing changed

Comment: Is it because of unicorn? https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#on-first-run-the-homepage-return-502-bad-gateway-nginx-after-3060-seconds

Comment: Or because of mysql? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/7#note_44271

Comment: The unicorn sulution helped thanks ! :)

Comment: Pk, I have added an answer illustrating that possible error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, a 502 error can be linked to unicorn. See:

- "[On first run the homepage return 502 bad gateway (nginx) after 30/60 seconds](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#on-first-run-the-homepage-return-502-bad-gateway-nginx-after-3060-seconds)":

> First start seems slow so increase the unicorn timeout to something larger, say 200. (Or buy faster hardware)

```
vim config/unicorn.rb
sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab restart
```

(with [`config/unicorn.rb.example`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/unicorn.rb.example) as an example)

Comment: @DenisShevchenko I have added the full path.