# "GitLab is not responding." 502 on Ubuntu 14.04 after starting server

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I have just installed GitLab on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit server. I did so using the Omnibus package as indicated in the [download page](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/). There were no error messages during the install and all the remarks from the script were displayed in green.

When I access the server through port 80 I get the following:

[image]

Following the [Trouble Shooting Guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide) I tried to query the status, but the result is also an error:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

I tried to access the logs but the `unicorn.stderr.log` file is nowhere to be found in the system.

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350526/installing-gitlab-on-ubuntu-12-04) with the same error on Ubuntu 12.04, to which the solution is to increase the unicorn timeout. I have tried to do so but the error message remains.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a lag of some 5 minutes from the moment gitlab is started/restarted to the point when it is actually able to process requests. Here is an example from the log:

```
2015-01-08_09:00:57.37719 [13326] 08 Jan 10:00:57.377 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 0
2015-01-08_09:00:57.37722 [13326] 08 Jan 10:00:57.377 * The server is now ready to accept connections at /var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket

[...]

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.676879 #13351]  INFO -- : listening on addr=127.0.0.1:8080 fd=11
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.677663 #13351]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.690283 #13351]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket fd=12
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.716769 #13413]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=13413
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.735878 #13351]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.846635 #13416]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=13416
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.837438 #13413]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2015-01-08T10:04:48.863110 #13416]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

Before Unicorn reports that it is up and running on port 8080, the "GitLab is not responding" message will be displayed. So all one has to do is wait.

Comment: This is still true in mid 2016, one wishes that the 502 page would be changed to say "alternatively, gitlab may still be starting up, please wait" if the uptime on some core process is less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Also, what process could ever take 10 minutes to start? Windows itself starts in 10 seconds, so does Linux. "It's 2016, come on!"

Comment: Its mid 2018 and it's still pretty much the same except it was up in about a minute or two.. I just upgraded to `ce-10.8` and when I tried accessing it on web I kept getting `502` for about a minute (or slightly more) then it worked as explained in answer.

Comment: Still the same functionality as of `gitlab-ee 11.0.2`. Thought I'd have to role back there for a second....

Comment: I think everyone who has ever GitLab'd has had this post-upgrade moment ... "Uh, is it EVER going to come back up?" and then it does. :)

Comment: 2020 and this is still valid

Comment: 2021, still valid.

Comment: almost 2022....and still valid

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It started happening suddenly. `unicorn_stderr.log` only shows several lines with this message: `I, [2022-04-22T17:57:04.038Z #26065]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list`. Have you found the solution to 502 error?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the similar problem as I have installed GitLab EE on CentOS 7.5 64 bit server in the year of the end of 2018.

[image]

The most important thing you must pay attention to is **Make sure your server is under the minimum requirements of performance!**

[In the official documentation of GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html#cpu),your server must be at least 2 cores and 8GB RAM.

[image]

**If your server is less than 2 cores and 8GB RAM.You can have a try to make a Swap to get more memories,and then reconfigure and restart your GitLab.If you still have this kind of situation,so pay attention to another big and terrible problem about first start of Gitlab:**

It may take a long time,maybe some minutes to load the first page after GitLab installation as the above answer saied!

["GitLab is not responding." 502 on Ubuntu 14.04 after starting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816046/gitlab-is-not-responding-502-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-starting-server/27836496#27836496)

> Note:If you have a server with lower performance such as: 1 core & 1GB RAM,it will be 502 at most time,even if you try to make the Swap to 8GB RAM,it's not working,the only way you can do is to make the performance of the server more than 2 cores & 8GB RAM minimum.

Some other methods for you to find more detail useful information:

- We can use `gitlab-ctl tail` to get the detail information and then copy the log and find the key words such as warning,failed and so on.
- You can go to the sub-directory of `/var/log/gitlab` to find the log to get some information.

Answer (score -1):

If it is showing 502 bad gateway try running the following command from your gitlab server.

```
sudo service gitlab-runsvdir start
```

If you are facing 504. Restart the server from the AWS/ GCP.