# Gitlab not responding

Tags: git, gitlab

I set up a git server with Gitlab last week, and all was working fine. All of the sudden, in the last day it just stopped working. When I try to access it in a browser, it just sticks until I get a 504 (Gateway Time-out). When I try to push it just sits there.

On the same server, Webmin is installed and I can access that. I can access the server fine via SSH. I tried disabling the firewall temporarily to see if that was where it was getting hung up, but no luck.

I realize this isn't much to go on, but any ideas?

Comment: what does gitlab-ctl status say? It lists all services for gitlab.

Comment: @Luceos Lists a bunch of pids, but it looks like everything is running.

Comment: @Luceos I tried gitlab-ctl restart, and now I'm getting a 502 on a gitlab error page. I guess that's progress of a kind lol.

Comment: Please have a look at this link also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27836496/1592107