# GItLab 502 error

Tags: nginx, gitlab, unicorn

I have set up gitlab on cent OS but have got stuck in a 502 error and not sure where to go, I have upgraded my server as I feared it was Memory but the error is the same after upgrade.

gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.adamprocter.co.uk:8081'
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
```

My server is running its own nginx as well for other service on port 80 etc but I could not get gitlab to even get a 502 with - nginx['enable'] = false and my own settings in my custom.conf so I think this should work configure seem ok as does restart

```
ok: run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 32665) 1s
ok: run: logrotate: (pid 32673) 0s
ok: run: nginx: (pid 32680) 1s
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 32697) 0s
ok: run: redis: (pid 32705) 0s
ok: run: sidekiq: (pid 32733) 0s
ok: run: unicorn: (pid 32737) 0s
```

but tail has this error

```
2016-04-15_20:31:17.45447 2016/04/15 16:31:17 error: proxyRoundTripper: GET "/" failed with: "dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: permission denied"
```

also further in the log

```
2016-04-15_20:45:27.58466   from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2016-04-15_20:45:27.58469   from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2016-04-15_20:45:27.60371 master failed to start, check stderr log for details
2016-04-15_20:45:28.61194 failed to start a new unicorn master
2016-04-15_20:45:28.63357 starting new unicorn master
2016-04-15_20:45:30.23368 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:778:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log (Errno::EACCES)
```

I had tried to edit permissions but I dont know if I did it right... and made no difference

```
sudo chmod 0660 /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
sudo chown nginx:gitlab-www /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
```

Comment: did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816046/gitlab-is-not-responding-502-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-starting-server

Comment: I figured this out - i seemed to have a broken install and a full clean out and reinstalled work plus I was given a lot of help with my nginx set up