# GitLab 502 error and unicorn always restart

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I installed **gitlab** in **Ubuntu** system successfully. But when I tried to access it via ***http://localhost:8181/gitlab*** , it showed me **502 Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond.**
I googled and tried the methods googled, but not worked. I also tried to change the **unicorn['port'] to different port**, but same error.

I run `gitlab-ctl status` and find out the **unicorn pid** is changing always.

I run `gitlab-ctl tail unicorn` and here the logs:

```
    ==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
ArgumentError: Already running on PID:809 (or pid=/opt/gitlab/var/unicorn/unicorn.pid is stale)
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:195:in `pid='
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:127:in `start'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2018-05-30_06:38:28.57658 master failed to start, check stderr log for details

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
ArgumentError: Already running on PID:809 (or pid=/opt/gitlab/var/unicorn/unicorn.pid is stale)
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:195:in `pid='
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:127:in `start'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2018-05-30_06:38:29.62413 failed to start a new unicorn master
2018-05-30_06:38:29.67502 starting new unicorn master
2018-05-30_06:38:30.38160 master failed to start, check stderr log for details

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
ArgumentError: Already running on PID:809 (or pid=/opt/gitlab/var/unicorn/unicorn.pid is stale)
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:195:in `pid='
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:127:in `start'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2018-05-30_06:38:31.43073 failed to start a new unicorn master
2018-05-30_06:38:31.48246 starting new unicorn master
2018-05-30_06:38:32.19747 master failed to start, check stderr log for details
2018-05-30_06:38:33.24646 failed to start a new unicorn master
2018-05-30_06:38:33.29837 starting new unicorn master

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
ArgumentError: Already running on PID:809 (or pid=/opt/gitlab/var/unicorn/unicorn.pid is stale)
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:195:in `pid='
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:127:in `start'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2018-05-30_06:38:34.00485 master failed to start, check stderr log for details
2018-05-30_06:38:35.05395 failed to start a new unicorn master
2018-05-30_06:38:35.10656 starting new unicorn master

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
ArgumentError: Already running on PID:809 (or pid=/opt/gitlab/var/unicorn/unicorn.pid is stale)
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:195:in `pid='
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:127:in `start'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
```

Hope anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

PS: I have **disabled** **Nginx** by setting `nginx['enable'] = false`
And add proxy_pass in **apache2.conf**:

```
ProxyPass /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:8181/gitlab
```

And gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = true
# gitlab_workhorse['ha'] = false
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"

unicorn['worker_timeout'] = 600
###! Minimum worker_processes is 2 at this moment
###! See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18771
unicorn['worker_processes'] = 2

### Advanced settings
# unicorn['listen'] = '127.0.0.1'
unicorn['port'] = 12148

web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
web_server['username'] = 'www-data'
web_server['group'] = 'www-data'

nginx['enable'] = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem as I have installed GitLab EE on CentOS 7.5 64 bit server.

[image]

The most important thing you must pay attention to is **Make sure your server is under the minimum requirements of performance!**

[In the official documentation of GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html#cpu),your server must be at least 2 cores and 8GB RAM.

[image]

**If your server is less than 2 cores and 8GB RAM.You can have a try to make a Swap to get more memories,and then reconfigure and restart your GitLab.If you still have this kind of situation,so pay attention to another big and terrible problem about first start of Gitlab:**

It may take a long time,maybe some minutes to load the first page after GitLab installation!

["GitLab is not responding." 502 on Ubuntu 14.04 after starting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816046/gitlab-is-not-responding-502-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-starting-server/27836496#27836496)

> Note:If you have a server with lower performance such as: 1 core & 1GB RAM,it will be 502 at most time,even if you try to make the Swap to 8GB RAM,it's not working,the only way you can do is to make the performance of the server more than 2 cores & 8GB RAM minimum.

Some other methods for you to find more detail useful information:

- We can use `gitlab-ctl tail` to get the detail information and then copy the log and find the key words such as warning,failed and so on.
- You can go to the sub-directory of `/var/log/gitlab` to find the log to get some information.